# Customize Apche solr autocomplete module

Tags: search, ajax

I want to display apache solr autocomplete keywords suggestion to be grouped like:-

----Suggestion from taxonomy-----

- term1
- term2
- term3

----Suggestion from products---

- product3
- product4
- product10

----Suggestion from pages---

- contentX
- contentY
- contentZ

Actually I am new in drupal, so could somebody help me how's it possible?